# List all users from a sqlite table using Yesod Haskell

Tags: html, database, sqlite, haskell, yesod

I am new to Yesod and would like to know how do I list all users from a table user. The database used is sqlite. Here is the function

```
getAllUsersR :: Handler Html
getAllUsersR = do "getAllUsersR not implemented yet!"
```

and this is the table users

```
CREATE TABLE "user"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"ident" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
"password" VARCHAR NULL,CONSTRAINT "unique_user" UNIQUE ("ident"))
```

Comment: What have you tried other than just setting up the function and the database?

Comment: I tried stuff with runDB and then defaultLayout but nothing seems to work, I dont quite understand how this works

Comment: Have you checked out the [RawSQL cookbook](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/RawSQL) for yesod?

Comment: I did, though it wasn't really helpful because there are only examples without many explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the authenticated user you can write:

```
getUserProfileR :: Handler RepHtml
getUserProfileR = do

  userId <- requireAuthId
  Entity _ userData <- runDB $ selectFirst [UserProfileUser ==. userId] [] >>= return.fromJust

  defaultLayout $ do
    setTitle "User profile"
    $(widgetFile "userprofile")
```

to list all, remove filter, use `select` instead `selectFirst` and write (on widget) some like

```
<h1>User list</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name
    <th>Mail
    <th>...
  $forall (Entity _ userData) <- userList
    <tr>
      <td>#{userProfileName userData}
      <td>#{userProfileMail userData}
      <td>...
```

(excuse me not write a complete and tested solution, but I have not a dev sandbox here)

**EDIT**

A full and tested example.
(do you need yesod-platform and yesod-bin)

```
$ ghc-pkg list | grep yesod-[0-9]
    yesod-1.2.2.1
$ yesod init
$ cd userList
```

for simplicity edit "Handler/Home.hs" file and add

```
getUserListR :: Handler Html
getUserListR = do
  users <- runDB $ selectList [] []
  defaultLayout $ do
    setTitle "Public user list!"
    [whamlet|
        <h1>User list</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Mail
          $forall (Entity _ userData) <- users
            <tr>
              <td>#{userIdent userData}
    |]
```

add next line into "config/routes"

```
/userlist UserListR GET
```

to test

```
$ cabal install
$ yesod devel
```

enter some users login in and login out

```
http://site:port/auth/login
(do login)
http://site:port/auth/logout
```

list users with

```
http://site:port/userlist
```

;)

Comment: Could you explain how this works? It says UserProfileUser is not in scope, and the the widgetFile should be inside templates right?

Comment: @PaktwisHomayun `UserProfile` is some db entity, if you are using yesod persistence and yesod auth plugin (recommended) you have `User` entity, you can use it instead `UserProfile`. For `widgetFile` question yes, in templates directory but look for exact names ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped! Is there also a way to separate the html? To put the code inside whamlet into another file, and link it to the getUserListR function. I thought that putting $(widgetFile "users") at the end would do the trick, but it didnt. (where "users" is a file users.hamlet inside templates with that html code)

Comment: `$(widgetFile "filename")` is a specific function from scaffolded sites and simply put each `filename.ext` into `templates` directory with `ext` any of `hamlet`, `julius` and/or `lucius`. Of course, you can/must read http://www.yesodweb.com/book :)